# Large text cause lag in recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lag

I'm using recycle view.

When I set a large text in textview in `onBindViewHolder` method, recycle view encounters a lag. What's wrong?

This is my code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {
   holder.textviewContent.setText(posts.get(position).spanRange);
}
```

Comment: please make it clear. what you want to do? and show to log details

Comment: @AMANSINGH recycle view scrolls slowly and has lag, in my adaptor i just set text from my db, and this text is more than one line. when i set static small text, recycle view scrolls smoothly and works fine.

Comment: this code is fine. I think you make mistake anywhere else. try to put that code

Comment: @AMANSINGH when I comment this code, everything works fine. I also activate  strike mode and there is not any process in main thread.